# having problem with webview encoding in android

Tags: android, encoding, webview

I got a page set in a wrong encoding(big5)

I wish to open it in android webview (loadUrl) with utf-8.

I have tried setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8") but it doesn't work ,

nothing changed the page still opened in big5.

so I made a experiment opening a utf-8 page with setDefaultTextEncodingName("big5")

there is no garbled it show the same as opening with utf-8 .

I wonder that when will the setDefaultTextEncodingName function works?

any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Try This----

```
        webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        webView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        webView.setFocusable(false);
        webView.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("UTF-8");
        String mimeType = "text/html";
        String encoding = "utf-8";
        String htmlText = Constant_Api.aboutUsList.getApp_faq();

        String text = "<html><head>"
                + "<style type=\"text/css\">@font-face {font-family: MyFont;src: url(\"file:///android_asset/fonts/montserrat_alternates_medium.otf\")}body{font-family: MyFont;}"
                + "</style></head>"
                + "<body>"
                + htmlText
                + "</body></html>";

        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text, mimeType, encoding, null);
```

Comment: Did you try this with big5 encoded contents in htmlText?